# OSError: Tensorflow version must >= 1.4.0-dev20171024

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have tensorflow 1.4.0 installed and I am trying to run a github project. But when I run the code, it gives the following error

```
OSError: Tensorflow version must >= 1.4.0-dev20171024
```

I have tried installing tensorflow nightly and tensorflow 1.14.0 but the problem persists.

Here is the link to the project that I am trying to run https://github.com/captainjtx/SimpleText

Comment: can you check if you are inside the correct virtual environment where the updated TensorFlow is accessible?

Comment: @Doodle yes I am in the correct virtual environment.

Comment: @can you just verify by opening terminal running pip freeze in the virtual env to see if its there?

Comment: The error makes no sense in isolation, include code or link to the repo that is producing the problem.

Comment: The changes are 2: 1) You are actually still using an environment with the wrong tensorflow version (maybe you forgot to activate the venv?) 2) The library has a bogus checks so it's simply broken and you'd have to fix it. We have **0** chances of determining which of the two is it and how to fix it. Maybe instead of opening a question on StackOverflow you'd like to [ask an Oracle instead](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle)?

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro Have edited the question, please find the link

Comment: @Doodle pip freeze shows tensorflow version 1.14.0